# Second Nested Foreach prints nothing

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make a list with each of these items, countries prints fine but the second foreach prints nothing i do not understand

```
   $countries = array('abc','def','ghi' );
    foreach ($countries as $key) {
        echo "<ul> ".$key;
                $character = characters::where('country',$key);
                foreach ($personaje as $p) {
                   echo $ch->name ;
                }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

it should something be like this, and i am 100% assured that the names of the table and the $key match, i did it with artisan's tinker

- abc { 
  -x 
   -y
   }
- def { 
  -z
   }
- ghi { 
  }

Comment: You are reading characters here `$character = characters::where('country',$key);` and in the `foreach` loop below, you are using `$personaje`. Where did that come from?

Comment: As @linuxartisan notes, `$personaje` comes from nowhere. Also you have to execute queries after building them; use `$character = characters::where('country',$key)->get();`

Comment: yes sorry its because i didnt translate $personaje to $character, that one slip off.  still that was not the problem because it prints the first foreach but the second one its just ignored i dont know why. it doesnt print anything

Comment: it was because i forgot tu use ->get();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$countries = array('abc','def','ghi' );
foreach ($countries as $key) {
    echo "<ul> ".$key;
            $character = characters::where('country',$key)->get();
            foreach ($character as $ch) {
               echo $ch->name ;
            }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this section of code, based on the snippet you provided:

```
        $character = characters::where('country',$key);
        foreach ($personaje as $p) {
           echo $ch->name ;
```

1. It looks like you're trying to do a query to get the $character
   variable but you're not executing it. Add a "get" to the end of the
   statement:

   $character = characters::where('country',$key)->get();
2. Your second foreach loop uses a variable **$personaje**, which
   hasn't been defined yet, at least in the code you provided. Should
   it be **$character** instead?
3. Your foreach loop uses "$personaje as $p", but you never use the
   variable **$p** in your loop. Instead, you're echoing **$ch->name**. The
   variable **$ch** doesn't exist in the code you've provided.

Comment: Yes it was because i forgot to use ->get();